# how to handle multiple `loading` states with redux architecture in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, redux

How do you guys handle multiple `loading` states with redux pattern in Flutter?

So here is my case:

`I have 3 pages, each page calls a different API and shows a loading HUD while requesting the API.`

**Sub-Question#1** How do i manage these isLoading states?

If i do it in the `AppState` , i need  to add multiple boolean properties to it, something like:

```
class AppState {
  final bool apiOneIsLoading;
  final bool apiTwoIsLoading;
  final bool apiThreeIsLoading;
  // other properties, bla bla...
}
```

However, Adding to many properties to the `AppState` class doesn’t sounds great I guess...

**Sub-Question#2** How do I update the UI when the `loading` state changes?

One solution I come up with is to create actions for both `loading` and `loaded` state, like so:

```
class SomeMiddleware extends MiddlewareClass<AppState> {
  @override
  void call(Store<AppState> store, dynamic action, NextDispatcher next) {
    if (action is CallAPIOneAction) {
      store.dispatch(APIOneLoadingAction());
      // call api one
      api.request().then((result){
        store.dispatch(APIOneLoadedAction())
      })
    }
  }
}
```

But if I do this, I need to create 2 extra actions for each API call, is this a good idea? is it okay to change or send new actions in middleware class on the fly?

Please let me know if you have a good solution, thanks!